# how to link .so files with CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, ubuntu-18.04

I want to rebuild a simple application based on a .cpp, a .h and multiple .so files. From what i've seen, my CMakeLists.txt should be like this :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)    
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)      
project(test C CXX)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)     
target_link_libraries(test ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libA.so ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libB.so)
```

All files are in the same folder. I previously linked my .cpp with my .h file correctly. `cmake .` is giving me no error, but after using `make` i get :

```
main.cpp:(.text+0xf2d) : undefined reference to « pthread_create »
```

Which is a function that doesn't belong to my .h file so it should be in the .so file. I don't know if the issue comes from the link or the file .so itself.

I also have file with the same name like libA.so, libA.so.0 or libA.so.0.2, should i include all of these files in my executable ?

Comment: You need to link with pthreads, add the `pthread` library to `target_link_libraries`. It has nothing to do (most likely) with your other `.so` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message means that you have to add `pthread` to the list of linked libraries. In `target_link_libraries` you only list the library names without path, `lib` prefix and file extension:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)    
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)      
project(test C CXX)

find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)     
target_link_libraries(test A B Threads::Threads)
```

You can add paths with [`target_link_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_directories.html):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)    
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)      
project(test C CXX)

find_package(ThreadsREQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)     
target_link_directories(test PRIVATE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE A B Threads::Threads)
```

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSablik, `make` compiled without error, but launching the application give me segmentation fault (core dumped). So i guess this issue is resolved and this is a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The good way to do it is to define respective target which will represent library.

```
add_library(externalLibA SHARED IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(externalLibA 
    PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libA.so)
target_include_directories(externalLibA
    INTERFACE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

Then add this target as dependency of your target.

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC externalLibA)
```